# Value of this integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int^{+\infty}_{0} e^{ikx-x} \, dx$?

Making $ikx-x = x(ik-1)$, I calculate it as (infinity - 1) which is infinity? Is this true?

Comment: Depends on what $k$ is, and (especially) depends on what $i$ is.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT** In general, assuming $k \ne 1/i$
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{x(ik-1)} = \left. \frac{e^{ikx}}{e^x(ik-1)} \right|_0^\infty
= \frac{-1}{ik-1} = \frac{1}{1-ik}
$$
since $e^{ikx} = \cos(kx) + i\sin(kx)$ is bounded.